# How to calculate conductivity / electron mobility from theory?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, greens-functions

Is there a way to make quantitative statements about the conductivity of materials with band theory?

If not I should still be able to get information about the conductivity from Green-Kubo relations of the electron wavefunctions in the material, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking are transport properties of materials, which represent the response of the system to an external perturbation (such as electric field) so that you cannot obtain just from band structure.

For the transport of the classical particle, you can solve the Boltzmann transport equation, from which you can derive the Drude formula for conductivity. For fully quantum treatment, you can use nonequilibrium Green's function method (or [Keldysh formalism](https://isis.ku.dk/kurser/blob.aspx?feltid=55674)), from which you can derive the current formula and transmission coefficient.

From bandstructure, you can obtain mobility, see section3.4 in [this paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2016/ta/c6ta06806e#!divAbstract).

Comment: so only from band theory without additional input I cannot get it, right?

Comment: What you are asking is transport properties, which represent the response of the system to an external perturbation (such as electric field) so that you cannot obtain just from band structure. Boltzmann equation (you can derive Drude formula for conductivity from it) and NEGF (transmission can be obtained, see Suprio Datta or google Keldysh's formalism) are the right ways.

Comment: but a little information about transport properties must be contained in band theory, otherwise you couldn't use it to distinguish between isolators and conductors, no?

Comment: You are right. Actually, one can calculate the electron mobility (distinguish with conductivity)  of materials from the conduction band minimum.

Comment: wait, from electron mobility you'll get the condictivity, no? Quote: Conductivity is proportional to the product of mobility and carrier concentration. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_mobility

Comment: and do you have a good reference on how to calculate the electron mobility from the conduction band minimum?

Comment: See section3.4 https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2016/ta/c6ta06806e#!divAbstract

Comment: cool. would be nice if you edit your answer to include all the helpful comments